# Quicksort with insertion sort in java

Tags: java, recursion, quicksort, insertion-sort

Hello I have been trying to implement my quicksort algorithm with insertion sort according to how our teacher told us, but I just can't figure out exactly what to do...And my teacher's pseudo code seems doesn't seem to help me much... Anyways, I have searched online but I can't find anything.
Here is the pseudo code he gaves us

```
voidTQuickSort(int[]A, low,high)
while low < high do
p = DPartition(A,low,high)
TQuicksort(A,low,high)
low = p + 1
end while
```

He also said "In quicksort switch to insertionSort for recursive calls on small subarrays, after partitioning, first recurse smaller subarray and then make a tail call to larger subarray"

First, I'd like to know, what is a tail call, and which array is he talking about? In my original quicksort I have this

```
public void quicksort(int numbers[], int start, int end)   
    {   
        //Condition to continue recursion
        if(start < end)
        {
            //Set up my index as the start or end point for recursion
            int myIndex = partition(numbers, start, end);

            //Recursive algorithm for left and right side of the array
            quicksort(numbers, start, myIndex-1);
            quicksort(numbers, myIndex + 1, end);
        }
    }
```

And in my attempt, I get a stack overflow, however, if I place those two sub arrays back into while loop, my runtime goes from 1 ms on quicksort, to 24 ms for the so called "improved" quicksort

Here's the attempt

```
public void quicksortImproved(int numbers[], int start, int end)   
    {   

        //Condition to continue recursion
        while(start < end)
        {
            //Set up my index as the start or end point for recursion
            int myIndex = partition(numbers, start, end);

            //Recursive algorithm
            quicksortImproved(numbers, start, end);
            start = myIndex + 1;
        }
        insertionSortTwo(numbers);


    }
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you

Function partition and insertionsortTwo

```
public int partition(int[] numbers, int start, int end)
    {
        //Declaring my pivot, start and end indexes
        int pivot = numbers[end];
        int small = start;
        int big = end - 1;

        //Begin loop while index of small is less than index of big
        while(small <= big)
        {
            //If the element @ numbers[small] is smaller than element at pivot
            //Then increment small index by 1
            while (small <= big && numbers[small] <= pivot)
            {
                small++;
            }
            //If the element @ numbers[big] is bigger than element at pivot
            //Then decrement index by 1
            while(big >= small && numbers[big] >= pivot)
            {
                big--;
            }
            //If small index is smaller than big index
            //Swap elements @ number[small] with element @ number[big]
            if(small < big)
            {
                numbers[small] = returnFirst(numbers[big], numbers[big] = numbers[small]);
            }
        }
        //Swap pivot with the presumed middle element and return small index
        numbers[end] = returnFirst(numbers[small], numbers[small] = numbers[end]);
        return small;
    }


    public void insertionSortTwo(int[] numbers)
    {
        //Loop from index 1 to end, element @ numbers[0] is in the sorted array
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++)
        {
            //Setting up second array index variable
            //Loop to create new array in sorted order
            for(int j = i; j > 0 && numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]; j--)
            {
                //If element @ number[j] is smaller than element @ number[j - 1]
                //swap element @ numbers[j] with element @ numbers[j - 1] and decrement j
                numbers[j] = returnFirst(numbers[j - 1], numbers[j - 1] = numbers[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: post the functions partition and insertionSortTwo if you want us to be able to help

Comment: Hey, just posted my partition and insertionTwo!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should write a test checking if your method actually sorts the array. It will save you a lot of time.

> He also said "In quicksort switch to insertionSort for recursive calls on small subarrays, after partitioning, first recurse smaller subarray and then make a tail call to larger subarray"
>   First, I'd like to know, what is a tail call, and which array is he talking about?

A tail call is the final call in a method.

I think he wants you to first sort the shortest of both subarrays and then the longest, after the partitioning. I'm not sure why he would want that though.

He also asks to use insertionsort for small subarrays. Therefor, your quicksort should look something like this:

```
public void quicksort(int numbers[], int start, int end) {  
    if(start < end) {
        if(start + 10 > end) {
            insertionsort(numbers, start, end);
        } else {
            int myIndex = partition(numbers, start, end);
            quicksort(numbers, start, myIndex-1);
            quicksort(numbers, myIndex + 1, end);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes everything sorts, I have checked it already, from previous questions. He wants us to use a while loop, but I figured out if I pass in myIndex-1 into my quicksortImproved recursive call, it sorts just fine, but barely better run time than normal quicksort, but I agree your alg looks much better, thank you!

Comment: Well, in quicksortImproved you simply use insertionSort **for the whole array** at the very end. That's cheating and of course a lot slower :-)